# Tailwindcss bg-[${props}] not render using react js from api

Tags: reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css

Why the color bg-[{props}] in tailwind is not render ?

in API i have to color
colorLeft : #DC2626
colorRight : #059669

and in my component cards im parse the color like
`bg-[{props.colorLeft}]`
`bg-[{props.colorRight}]`

and then i call that with map.
colorLeft = {event.colorLeft}
colorRight = {event.colorRight}

in console, i see it's true like this
[console picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1BbR.png)

this is my code
**HomePageContent**

```
import EventsCard from "../component/EventCard";
import TopProduct from "../component/TopProduct";
import { ChartHalfDoughnut } from "../component/Chart";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios"

function HomePageContent(filteredApp) {

  const [event, setEvent] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getEvent = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://192.168.20.2:3000/api/v1/event-upcoming")
    setEvent(response.data)
  } catch(error) {
    console.log("Error Api Event")
    console.log(error)
  }
}
getEvent()
  }, [])


  const formatCurrency = (money) => {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('id-ID',
      { style: 'currency', currency: 'IDR', minimumFractionDigits: 0 }
    ).format(money);
  }

  const eventDate = date => {
    return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString("id", {day:'numeric', month:'long',     year:'numeric'})
  }

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
      <div className="grid col-span-1 place-content-center rounded-md shadow-md ">
        <ChartHalfDoughnut />
        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 mt-10 gap-y-12">
          <TopProduct icon="Icon" title="Siam" />
          <TopProduct icon="Icon" title="Sima" />
          <TopProduct icon="Icon" title="Sirak" />
          <TopProduct icon="Icon" title="Siku" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-span-2 rounded-md shadow-md p-10 space-y-5 max-h-[46rem] overflow-y-scroll">
      {
        event.data?.map((event) => (
          <EventsCard
            key={event.id}
            icon={event.icons[0]?.url}
            title={event.title}
            subTitle={event.subTitle}
            date={eventDate(event.date)}
            price={event.price === 0 ? "Gratis" : formatCurrency(event.price)}
            colorLeft = {event.colors[0].left}
            colorRight = {event.colors[0].right}s
          />
            ))
          }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePageContent;
```

**EventCard**

```
<div className={`flex relative bg-[${props.colorRight}] ov1erflow-hidden rounded-t-    lg`}>
    <div className={`absolute bg-[${props.colorLeft}] w-8/12 left-0 right-0 top-0     bottom-0 skew-x-[45deg] -mx-[20%]`}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be found in the document：Tailwind doesn’t include any sort of client-side runtime, so class names need to be statically extractable at build-time, and can’t depend on any sort of arbitrary dynamic values that change on the client. Use inline styles for these situations, or combine Tailwind with a CSS-in-JS library like Emotion if it makes sense for your project.you should do dynamically select a complete class name.

```
<EventsCard
 key={event.id}
 icon={event.icons[0]?.url}
 title={event.title}
 subTitle={event.subTitle}
 date={eventDate(event.date)}
 price={event.price === 0 ? "Gratis" : formatCurrency(event.price)}
 colorLeft = {'bg' + event.colors[0].left}
 colorRight = {'bg' + event.colors[0].right}
/>
```

Comment: it's not working too

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer.
using backgrounColor from css.

```
<div className={`flex relative overflow-hidden rounded-t-lg`} style={{backgroundColor:props.colorRight}}>
    <div className={`absolute w-8/12 left-0 right-0 top-0 bottom-0 skew-x-[45deg] -mx-[20%]`} style={{backgroundColor:props.colorLeft}}>
```